# Flask - How to use config.from_object()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm having an error:

```
RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.
```

While trying to set up my flask app:

init.py

```
from config import Config
from .models import User
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager 

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
```

config.py

```
import os

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(12)
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:////home/zepp/project/users.db"
```

I can't understand what I'm missing here. It seems like Config Class is not being read by the init file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the app initialization in a function, you can put that outside the function then it should work.

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db.init_app(app)
```

Or if you need to use the function, you can put the SQLAlchemy initialization inside the function.

```
def create_app():
    db = SQLAlchemy()
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
```

Or you can just pass the app inside the SQLAlchemy() initialization:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```